# How do I check if two simple 2D arrays have the same 1D arrays? (order and repetitions doesn't matter)

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, equals, deepequals

**My main objective is to return if all elements, int[ ], of a 2D Array ,int[ ][ ], are present in another 2D Array.**

I already tried to use `Arrays.deepEquals()` but in this case, the order of the elements would matter and that's not the purpose.

- Int[ ][ ] arrays wouldn't be longer than 15, for example.
- Int[ ][ ] arrays have always the same length.
- Int[ ][ ] arrays order doesn't matter, but Int[ ] arrays does.
- Int[ ] arrays would always be a pair.

**Expected:**

```
int[][] array1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}, {3,4}} // Main Array

int[][] array2 = {{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {3,4} {1, 2}}} // Expected: true

int[][] array3 = {{6, 3}, {1, 2}, {7,4} {0, 1}}} // Expected: false
```

**This is my solution/try:**

```
// Check if an int[] array (element) belongs to an int[][] array.

public static boolean inVector(int[][] 2dArray, int[] 1dArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2dArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2dArray[i].length; j++) {

            if (1dArray[0] == 2dArray[i][0] && 1dArray[1] == 2dArray[i][1]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


// Check if all int[] arrays of an int[][] belong to another int[][] array.

// This is not working properly

public boolean allBelongs() {

  boolean belongs = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
     
     if (inVector(array1, array2()[i])) {
        belongs = true;
     }
     
     else {
        belongs = false;
     }
  }

    return belongs;
}
```

**EDIT:** I solved the problem reversing the logic of the solution. Posted own answer.

Comment: Do you have specific performance requirements? How large do you expect the arrays to be?

Comment: For example, if the arrays are typically very small, the simplest and fastest solution is probably a nested loop that loops over each subarray A in the first array, and then for each subarray B in the second array, checks whether A deepequals B, and if that is the case for each A, return true, otherwise return false

Comment: No, I do not have any performance requirements.

Comment: Int[ ] arrays would always be a pair. :)

Comment: I'm expecting the int[ ] [ ] arrays to do not have a bigger length than 15, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IntBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/IntBuffer.html) which can wrap an `int[]` array and provide the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations reflecting the array’s content.

```java
public static boolean sameSubArrays(int[][] array1, int[][] array2) {
    if(array1 == array2) return true;
    HashSet<IntBuffer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int[] a: array1) set.add(IntBuffer.wrap(a));
    for(int[] a: array2) if(!set.contains(IntBuffer.wrap(a))) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This is simple and runs in linear time, hence, can cope with large arrays. It has the expected result for your test case.

```java
int[][] array1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}, {3,4}};
int[][] array2 = {{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
System.out.println(sameSubArrays(array1, array2)); // true
```

But it does not consider duplicates. If the number of occurrences must match for sub arrays with the same contents, you have to expand the solution to use a map to count the occurrences.

```java
public static boolean sameSubArrays(int[][] array1, int[][] array2) {
    if(array1 == array2) return true;
    if(array1.length != array2.length) return false;
    HashMap<IntBuffer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int[] a: array1) map.merge(IntBuffer.wrap(a), 1, Integer::sum);
    for(int[] a: array2)
        if(map.merge(IntBuffer.wrap(a), -1, Integer::sum) < 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Since your example has no duplicates, it still has the same result.

Comment: Does your first snippet check if they are equal, or just that array2 is a subset of array1? Looks like it would return true for non-empty array1 and empty array2.

Comment: @AndyTurner the first snippet checks whether all sub arrays of `array2` are also sub arrays of `array1`. You could augment it with a length check, but it still wouldn’t handle duplicates, so even then, `array2` could consist of just repetitions of one sub-array only. So for a “contains all of the other array” check, you’d have to use the second snippet.

Comment: Thank your for your answer Holger. I think this is the most simple and correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work. If the arrays are relatively small (for example, 2 by 4), it will likely be faster than other solutions:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static boolean isSubarrayUnordered(int[][] child, int[][] parent) {
    for (int[] childSubarray : child) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (int[] parentSubarray : parent) {
        if (Arrays.equals(childSubarray, parentSubarray)) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}, {3, 4}};
    int[][] array2 = {{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
    int[][] array3 = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {0, 999}, {3, 4}};

    System.out.println("array1 in array2? " + isSubarrayUnordered(array1, array2));
    System.out.println("array1 in array3? " + isSubarrayUnordered(array1, array3));
  }
}
```

For medium-sized arrays (maybe hundreds to thousands of total elements), it might be faster to create sorted copies of both arrays, and have two iterators over both arrays `itChild, itParent`. For each element of `itChild`, if the current element of `itParent` is equal (using `Arrays.equals`, then advance both `itChild` and `itParent`. Otherwise, advance only `itParent`. Repeat until there are either no more elements in `itChild` (return `true`) or no more elements in `itParent` (return `false`).

For extremely large arrays (millions to billions of elements), the costs of creating a copy may be prohibitively expensive. You will probably want to create a compressed representation of the array using something like a `sha256` hash, and then compare only the hashes of the elements. This has a small probability of returning the wrong answer though, if the array is extremely large.

Comment: Why are you using boxed `Boolean` in your method? Note that you are thinking too complicated for larger arrays; there is [a much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618387/2711488).

Comment: There's no reason for the boxed `Boolean`, edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: "you are thinking too complicated" -- under the hood, `IntBuffer` in your linked solution is using `hashCode` for efficient `equals` comparison, so the core idea is not complicated. Also, if the data is extremely large, then sha256 is going to be much faster than IntBuffer, because in the case where elements _are_ equal you have to compare each element. If the array is M X N (size N subarrays) then each equality check is O(N) vs O(1) with sha256. But yes, I agree that `IntBuffer` is a nice simple solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brandon. It helped me figuring out that with a different approach I could solve the problem,  Instead of verifying if ALL `int[]` are present in the `int[][]`, I could just verify if ONE `int[]` isn't present.

Comment: To calculate an sha256, you have to go over the entire array anyway and since an equal hash does not prove that the array is equal (for a large array), you also have to compare the elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of verifying if ALL int[] are present in the int[][], I can just verify if ONE int[] isn't present.**

```
public boolean allBelongs() {

  for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
 
    if (!inVector(array1, array2()[i])) {
       return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```